# Binary division - find a remainder

Tags: arithmetic, binary

I have difficulty in finding the remainder of the next expression: `111010011/1101`.

What I did:

```
111010011/1101
1101
---------
001100
  1101
---------
  0001101
     1101
---------
     0000
```

So the remainder is 0 (which is not correct). Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made several mistakes. Remember that in normal subtraction, you also don't have $123 - 456 = 777$. You have to carry the bits you lose from right to left to get a proper subtraction. And you have to subtract the highest power-$2$ multiple of $1101$ possible on each step, but $1101$ does not "fit" in $1100$ (as you did in the second line).

In any case, here's a proper division with remainder.

$$\begin{matrix}
\color{green}{1} & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{0} & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{1} & \\
\color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} &   &   &   &   &  \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \\
  &   &   &   & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} &  \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \\
  &   &   &   &   & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{0} & \\
\end{matrix}$$

So $\color{green}{111010011} = (100000 + 10 + 1) \cdot \color{red}{1101} + \color{blue}{1100}$, i.e. the remainder is $\color{blue}{1100}$.

We can verify the above by converting to decimal representations, in which case we get $\color{green}{467} = (32 + 2 + 1) \cdot \color{red}{13} + \color{blue}{12}$.